# How to supply parameters to constructors, not known in advance?

Tags: c#, createinstance

This function will load an assembly, let the user select a form from a list, and then try to invoke it. If successful, returning the form.

My problem is how to instantiate the constructor with parameters that is of the expected type.
if the constructor expect `List<string>` an empty `List<String>` should be supplied, not just null.

Any Ideas?

```
private Form SelectForm(string fileName)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
    var asmTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(F => F.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form)));
    string SelectedFormName;
    using (FrmSelectForm form = new FrmSelectForm())
    {
        form.DataSource = (from row in asmTypes
                           select new { row.Name, row.Namespace, row.BaseType }).ToList();

        if (form.ShowDialog(this) != DialogResult.OK)
            return null;
        SelectedFormName = form.SelectedForm;
    }

    Type t = asmTypes.Single<Type>(F => F.Name == SelectedFormName);
    foreach (var ctor in t.GetConstructors())
    {
        try
        {
            object[] parameters = new object[ctor.GetParameters().Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < ctor.GetParameters().Length; i++)
            {
                parameters[i] = ctor.GetParameters()[i].DefaultValue;
            }
            return Activator.CreateInstance(t, parameters) as Form;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What if it expects an `IList`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Suppose the constructor requires a list that must be nonempty, what should you add to the list to make it work? Or do you know that all ctors take only primitives, collections that can be empty but not null, or instances of objects that in turn have such constructors? In that case it might work

Comment: boiut letting the user choose the values- There's no way of figuring out what _sensible_ values to use. Eg. an empty list might be invliad

Comment: I want to have a generic way to generate variables, that are valid for the constructor. If the constructor have validation of the parameters supplied, and doens't accept empty data. that is beyond a generic way of supplying the parameters. i.e. you then need to know what the constructor wants/needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to create objects from types definitions this method works very well.

```
private Form SelectForm(string fileName,string formName)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
    var asmTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(F => F.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form)));

    Type t = asmTypes.Single<Type>(F => F.Name == formName);
    try
    {
        var ctor = t.GetConstructors()[0];
        List<object> parameters = new List<object>();
        foreach (var param in ctor.GetParameters())
        {
            parameters.Add(GetNewObject(param.ParameterType));
        }
        return ctor.Invoke(parameters.ToArray()) as Form;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

...

```
public static object GetNewObject(Type t)
{
    try
    {
        return t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new object[] { });
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what is a parameter type, replace:

```
parameters[i] = ctor.GetParameters()[i].DefaultValue;
```

to

```
parameters[i] = new List<string>();
```

If you don't know, you need create instance using same reflection methods:

```
object p1 = Activator.CreateInstance(parameters[i].ParameterType), 
return Activator.CreateInstance(t, [p1]) as Form;
```

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I am asking for, how to create those parameters. When I use DafaultValue, a string-list will just become null, which isn't a valid parameter to the constructor.

Comment: @Stig Hm...I wrote you what you should to do. The question is: do you know what parameters type should be, or it can be dynamic and you have no idea what type of parameter is? For dynamic: object p1 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(parameters[i])), then: return Activator.CreateInstance(t, [p1]) as Form;

Comment: If you have an interface, I think it can be a problem since you can't know what type to create that implements that interface...